# Deciding runAs in Test Class

Tags: unit-test

My question is how do I determine the user profile to be used as runAs by just analyzing the code ?

Can it be decided looking at any permission or any other factor ?

Let's assume I donot have any functional document right now.

Comment: It is not necessary to use runAs unless you are testing logic that is dependent on a specific user or profile attribute. Suggest you expand your question to explain more what you are looking for.

Comment: @KeithC- My current requirement is changing all runAs system admin scenarios to specific user runAs cases. So my question was is there any way to understand that from code?

Comment: Per-existing User and Profile objects are [visible in tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm) so you can pre-create the ones you need and query to get the right user. But my point is that most Apex code is unaffected by the User or Profile and adding runAs everywhere is a lot of clutter in your tests.

Comment: You need runAs for the cases where your snippet is going to execute for particular user's context and not as logged In user's context. To cover those methods/lines you can use runAs method. For rest of the code you can use logged In user's context. Also this is needed in situation like guest users.

Comment: Keeping in mind that custom sharing rules are not taken into account with run as so it is pretty much only useful if explicitly checking permissions or when using Queues like FF does. Also if adding set-up and non-setup records in same transaction

Answer (score 2):

Having a specific runAs user in testing is beneficial when:

- You have Hierarchical Custom Settings where certain users/profiles get certain 'settings' that other users do not -- and -- where the code uses these hierarchical settings to make decisions
- You have logic that depends (and this could include Validation Rules) that depends on the running user's Profile or UserRole
- You want to have a regression suite that verifies the presence of `with sharing` on classes (such as on VF controllers) that should, in fact, limit the number of records retrieved based on the running user
- You have logic that depends on the presence of a custom permission for a running user (this could also include VR or formulas)

Now, using code scans to infer the above will be daunting.

**Sharing**

A strategy to follow is to look at the OWD defined (assume it is correct) and then infer whether there are Write prohibitions for certain SObjects to users in certain roles or public groups - then look for the relevant classes to see if they are unintentionally subverting the intent of the sharing model.

To priortize, stick to SObjects that represent money or confidential information.

A couple of useful references are:

- [Apex Sharing and applying to Apex Enterprise Patterns](https://andyinthecloud.com/2016/01/10/apex-sharing-and-applying-to-apex-enterprise-patterns/)
- [When to run without sharing](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Without_Sharing)

**Specific users/profiles/roles/permissions**

Scan for logic (including VR and workflows) that is dependent on specific user name, profile names, custom permissions, or userRole names. Where such logic exists, especially in Apex, if you are currently running as sysad, then you are probably missing some code coverage/assert-regression use cases